# Python: Memory-efficient random sampling of list of permutations

Tags: python, permutation

I am seeking to sample n random permutations of a list in Python.

This is my code:

```
obj = [    5     8     9 ... 45718 45719 45720]
#type(obj) = numpy.ndarray

pairs = random.sample(list(permutations(obj,2)),k= 150)
```

Although the code does what I want it to, it causes memory issues. I sometimes receive the error `Memory error` when running on CPU, and when running on GPU, my virtual machine crashes.

How can I make the code work in a more memory-efficient manner?

Comment: If you knew how many permutations there were, you could choose a random sample of the numbers in that range, then walk though the list of permutations to get the ones you want, thus avoiding producing a list of *all* of them, which is the most likely cause of your memory issue.

Comment: ah interesting approach. I understand the first part (choosing a random sample of the numbers in the range of permutations), but what do you mean by 'walk through the list'? What would that entail?

Comment: @ScottHunter Error is not in the `random.sample` but in `permutations`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Pablo Ruiz's excellent answer, I suggest wrapping his sampling solution into a generator function that yields unique permutations by keeping track of what it has already yielded:

```
import numpy as np

def unique_permutations(sequence, r, n):
    """Yield n unique permutations of r elements from sequence"""
    seen = set()
    while len(seen) < n:
        # This line of code adapted from Pablo Ruiz's answer:
        candidate_permutation = tuple(np.random.choice(sequence, r, replace=False))

        if candidate_permutation not in seen:
            seen.add(candidate_permutation)
            yield candidate_permutation

obj = list(range(10))
for permutation in unique_permutations(obj, 2, 15):
    # do something with the permutation

# Or, to save the result as a list:
pairs = list(unique_permutations(obj, 2, 15))
```

My assumption is that you are sampling a small subset of the very large number of possible permutations, in which case collisions will be rare enough that keeping a `seen` set will not be expensive.

Warnings: this function is an infinite loop if you ask for more permutations than are possible given the inputs. It will also get increasingly slow an `n` gets close to the number of possible permutations, since collisions will get increasingly frequent.

If I were to put this function in my code base, I would put a shield at the top that calculated the number of possible permutations and raised a `ValueError` exception if `n` exceeded that number, and maybe output a warning if `n` exceeded one tenth that number, or something like that.

Comment: Interestingly enough solutions with no collision probabilities involved are also possible, I edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 4):

This avoids using `permutations` at all:

```
count = len(obj)
def index2perm(i,obj):
    i1, i2 = divmod(i,len(obj)-1)
    if i1 <= i2:
        i2 += 1 
    return (obj[i1],obj[i2])
pairs = [index2perm(i,obj) for i in random.sample(range(count*(count-1)),k=3)]
```

Comment: This approach is the way to go, unfortunately is not perfect obj = np.array([1,2,3,4]) will produce unstable results (sometimes not working) not sure where is the error.

Comment: @PabloRuiz: Note that an array is not a list; the original spec was for a `obj` to be a list.  Can you post the specific error you are seeing?

Comment: @PabloRuiz: If the problem was an index-out-of-bounds, or generating a permutation w/ duplicate values, I think that has (now) been addressed.

Comment: You miss a parenthesis in the function range, but besides that, now this looks to be a very efficient working solution. The if statement shifts up the diagonal avoiding it, that is nice and smart.

Comment: I love this solution, even though it take a little while to fully grasp. First I didn't like how it's specific to pairs, but thinking about it the approach is not too hard to generalize. For triples, you'd sample from `range(count*(count-1)*(count-2))` and `index2perm` would use a careful cascade of divmods and if statements. It'll be finicky debugging, but the result will be super efficient. I remain partial to my own solution, because it's easier to understand, but if I was to put this functionality into a library, hands down your solution wins.

Comment: One limitation about generalizing this approach to arbitrarily large tuples, though: `random.sample()` raises an OverflowError when given a range that's larger than a 63 bit int (because it casts to signed C ssize_t under the hood), so sampling an 8 element permutation from a set with 255 elements breaks.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid listing the permutation iterator that could be massive in memory. You can generate random permutations by sampling the list with `replace=False`.

```
import numpy as np
obj = np.array([5,8,123,13541,42])
k = 15
permutations = [tuple(np.random.choice(obj, 2, replace=False)) for _ in range(k)]
print(permutations)
```

This problem becomes much harder, if you for example impose no repetition in your random permutations.

**Edit, no repetitions code**

I think this is the best possible approach for the non repetition case.

We index all possible permutations from `1 to n**2-n` in a permutation matrix where the diagonal should be avoided. We sample the indexes without repetitions and without listing them, then we map the samples to the coordinates of the permutations and then we get the permutations from the indexes of matrix.

```
import random
import numpy as np

obj = np.array([1,2,3,10,43,19,323,142,334,33,312,31,12])
k = 150
obj_len = len(obj)

indexes = random.sample(range(obj_len**2-obj_len), k)
def mapm(m):
    return m + m //(obj_len) +1

permutations = [(obj[mapm(i)//obj_len], obj[mapm(i)%obj_len]) for i in indexes]
```

This approach is not based on any assumption, does not load the permutations and also the performance is not based on a while loop failing to insert duplicates, as no duplicates are ever generated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But I do want to impose no repetition in the random permutations

Comment: @matriz and do you consider (3,5) (5,3) repeated or valid?

Comment: @PabloRuiz If you're taking 150 sample permutations out of a very large space of possibilities, I would use this code here to sample permutations, and keep a set of "seen" permutations, discarding duplicates as they are generated.

Comment: @matriz you can check now

Comment: @PabloRuiz It took me a while to undestand your `mapm()` function, but that's a very clever solution, and certainly very efficient.